# Property 'split' does not exist on type 'string | number | {}'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new in Typescript. I am getting an error in which it is saying that the split does not exist on type number. Of course I have done the narrowing, by checking the type of value but it is of no use. Here is the code

**file.ts**

```
interface AIObject {
  CLARITY_CODE?: string | {};
  CARAT?: number | {};
  SHAPE_CODE?: string | {};
}

const numericKeys = [
    "CARAT",
  ];

const arrObj: AIObject[] = [
  {
    CLARITY_CODE: "DE",
    CARAT: 5,
    SHAPE_CODE: "SI",
  },
];

arrObj.map((obj: AIObject) => {
  let ov = Object.keys(obj);
  ov.forEach((val) => {
    if (typeof obj[val as keyof AIObject] === "string") {
      const check = obj[val as keyof AIObject]?.split("-");
      //     console.log(check);
      if (check.length === 2) {
        if (numericKeys.includes(val)) {
          obj[val as keyof AIObject] = { $gte: check[1], $lte: check[0] };
        } else {
          obj[val as keyof AIObject] = [...check];
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is happening because your `typeof` check on `obj[val]` does not work as a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#typeof-type-guards), like you are expecting. This is because there is no guarantee that obj[val] from the previous line will be the same when you use it later. Imagine an object with a custom getter for `val` that returned an value of a random type: because it's being called twice, the compiler doesn't know that it will have the same type, because it's being told it could be a string, number, or object.

One solution is to create a variable with `obj[val]` as its value, then your type guard will work as expected. [Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIEkDyAjAVhBMZAbwChkLkBhAGVQCV0AVATQH0rMARAUQH4AXMgDOYKKADmyAD4kAvgG5ylKg1RNByEAFcAttmgz5SysgDKACVQAFHh278ho8SCmzii0nNKkEAexBRLT1oYAQAaQgAT2FkAF5kAG1lCgAiVXp1VIAaUgBdJV8AoLgoKBxcIQwKgjBEvPiklJJm01oGZnZOXiFU3hzWlTUmIQBWXNNTSxs7bp5es3QB0zlcgp9S8rwAOl04AAcACkO-PCqsPFqASniAPhbTABsIIj8AN0aawm2Aa2jhE54K4mSjvbYwPxQHiIAAWxzecEeNzi9zIk0o-kCRGAkF0jVOuESCMeyDgsT%20UT8MDQF3whDygwowGphzAUX2ECpyBxEDxcX5yFSzkkqRuaPRk0xQQQMIIP0aPN022E%200eOMOqQAtKKQRLKAB6fWS4p%20Z7bR5%20CSHGVy4GMybM5DW2UIH7miCuMAw%20ICgBMYvtesdhx0ulCEX%2021ACEe2gAJhAAcSrgG9WnQXgiYjSeTolzqpd6Y1iMgACQSSBCG2uxIARjy2TLj0ryGrP0SAAYGp50%20i5MgII9hChxb2JQSsySycgKfnabUGglEtsV231mOVoHKN49Tvt3a5MDkEbMF7oAB3YDDxsSF4iMClSBx5DYKLIKC896SZBn4etvy6GG4CxHAIDPmeyDnpCjzPleyCUtoUDIKqcBRBIUB%20NoYHbKQQA)

Another potential solution is to just cast the value to a string before you call `.split()`. You know that it will be a `string`, you just need the type system to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using TypeScript you can define the data type where you are applying the condition in the if statement. This is known as Type Assertion.

(obj[val as keyof AIObject] **as string**) this will now treat the value as a string and your condition should work.